# iphone - NSDateFormatter problem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have an nsdateformatter

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

for value : `2010-01-01 05:00:00.000`
it returns the correct value

but for value: `2010-01-01 05:22:00.000`
it returns null.

According to the documentation if i am correct for minute i am suppose to use "mm"
So what's wrong with my code and why does it return nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter * f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSLog(@"%@", [f dateFromString:@"2010-01-01 05:00:00.000"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [f dateFromString:@"2010-01-01 05:22:00.000"]);
[f release];
```

Logs:

```
2010-11-16 16:44:11.867 EmptyFoundation[42477:a0f] 2010-01-01 05:00:00 -0700
2010-11-16 16:44:11.868 EmptyFoundation[42477:a0f] 2010-01-01 05:22:00 -0700
```

So it is parsing things correctly.  Thus, you are doing something wrong somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks clean to me. I tried it and got correct results:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"2010-01-02 03:44:55.666"];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSDateFormatter *f2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f2 setDateFormat:@"d. MMMM yyyy HH mm ss SSS"];
NSString *s = [f2 stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"Date is really %@",s);
```

Returned the following output:

```
2010-11-16 18:48:35.221 Test3[6407:207] 2010-01-02 03:44:55 -0500
2010-11-16 18:48:35.223 Test3[6407:207] Date is really 2. January 2010 03 44 55 666
```